# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'. > Job failed, see logs for details

Tags: android, build.gradle

i want to build my android application. but this error occur. please help me to resolve this error. thanks

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.

> Job failed, see logs for details

Comment: are you releasing you app.?

Comment: yes, but this error occur!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        /*debug {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }*/
    }
```

in your gradle